# x86 assembly procedure crashes, possibly overlooking simple error

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Hello this is my first time posting here, but I am working on a homework assignment that is to design an assembly function syracuse(N, sequence) with these given rules: 
1. if N is 1, end loop. 
2. if N is even, then N=N/2, goto beginning of loop
3. if N is odd, then N= 3N+1, goto beginning of loop

Pretty simple, then he wants us to display some information and create a report. However, I have been staring at this code for several hours now and I cannot figure out what is wrong. Once I comment out the call, the program works great and will not crash, otherwise it will crash. I think I am just overlooking something simple and fundamental, could any of you provide assistance?

Here is the code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h   
cr  EQU 0dh;carriage return
Lf  EQU 0ah;line feed 
.STACK  4096
.DATA
array   DWORD ?
n       DWORD   0
steps   DWORD   0   
prompt  BYTE    "Enter N: ", 0
count   BYTE    cr, Lf, "Total Numbers: "
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
result  BYTE    cr, Lf, "N: "

;result2    BYTE    cr, Lf, "Steps: "
lbl BYTE 11 DUP (?)
BYTE cr, Lf, 0
.CODE
_start    PROC
    output prompt ;ask for n
    input string, 40
    atod string ; convert to int
    mov n, eax  
    dtoa lbl, n ;convert to ascii
    output result; print out n

    push n
    push array
    call syracuse
    add esp, 8
    ret
_start    ENDP
syracuse PROC ; syracuse(n, array)
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx;save ebx
    push eax;save eax
    push esi
    mov eax, [ebp+8] ;first parameter 
    lea esi, [ebp+12] ;beginning of the array
            mov ecx, 0
    whileLoop:  inc ecx; ecx++
                mov [esi+4], eax
                cmp eax, 1
                je endLoop ;if n = 1, then end
                mov ebx, 2
                idiv ebx
                cmp edx, 0
                je evenProc ; if n is even

                ;if n is odd then 3N + 1
                shl eax, 1
                add eax, 2
                jmp whileLoop               
    evenProc: ;if n is even then N = N/2
        mov ebx, 2
        idiv eax
        jmp whileLoop
    endLoop:
        dtoa lbl, ecx
        output count;display count
        pop esi
        pop eax
        pop ebx
        pop ebp
        ret

syracuse ENDP
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a debugger and step through your assembly.  However, a few things leap out at me:

`array` isn't an array, it's just an uninitialized DWORD.

```
push n  
push array
```

This is backwards based on how `syracuse` accesses its arguments.  Generally, your calling convention would be right-to-left in push order.  If array is pushed first, its value would be at EBP+12 and n would be at EBP+8.

```
mov [esi+4], eax
```

ESI = EBP+12.  Therefore, [ESI+4] = [EBP+16] and that stack location likely stores the return address of start's caller; probably not a good idea to change it.  Since `array` isn't really an array and you're writing to the same location each time, you probably can skip using ESI altogether and use `mov [ebp+12], eax` instead (although you seem to be discarding the value entirely; perhaps you wanted to push the address of `array` onto the stack?).

```
idiv ebx
```

The idiv instruction divides the 64-bit integer EDX:EAX by the operand EBX, in this case.  Since you don't clear EDX, you may not get the result you desire (including integer overflow exceptions).  Try a `xor edx, edx` before the `idiv`.

I didn't really check to see if all of your logic is correct, just saw the above issues.

Comment: Awesome you fixed my crashing problem! Thank you so much for the help and not bashing me for making stupid mistakes!

Comment: @JamesLittle If the answer solved your question, make sure you accept it!